What is the best way to require "at least one of these keys"
(Edit: this is using ts 4.8.3)
Suppose I have a function that takes a Message object which, along with the subject and body, can include either a destination email address or a userId for which we should look up the address.
If I define a type like this:
type Message = {
  subject: string
  body: string
} & (
  { destinationUserID: string } |
  { destinationAddress: string }
)

Then it behaves as expected when defining a message:
const m: Message = {
  subject: 'foo',
  body: 'bar',
  // ts complains if at least one of address or userId are not present
  destinationAddress: 'xxxyyy',
}

But when I try to write a function that accepts a Message object like the one below, I get:

Property 'destinationUserID' does not exist on type '{ subject: string; body: string; } & { destinationAddress: string; }'

...and of course vice-versa when I try to reference destinationAddress.
And ok, I get that it's telling me "hey, you can't just assume that key exists, since this type accepts objects that don't have it!", but as you can see from the code, I'm not assuming it exists. I'm checking for it with ?. and have plans for either or both vars being undefined.
So clearly I'm misunderstanding something here, or maybe ts is just not being as smart as I want it to be. Either way, advice would be appreciated!
const processMessage = (m: Message) => {
  const emailAddress = m?.destinationUserID !== undefined // ts complains here
    ? getEmailByUserUUID(m.destinationUserID) // and here
    : m?.destinationAddress // and here

  if (emailAddress === undefined) throw new Error('Cannot find email')

  // send message...
}


Optional chaining doesn't guard against extra props. To say that destinationUserID is either string or absent, you need to mention it in all union members (a value of {subject: string; body: string; destinationAddress: string} might have a destinationUserID prop of type number or Date or anything. Unmentioned doesn't mean absent). The easiest way is shown in this playground by having it optional (string or undefined) in the base type. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz well that does solve the problem. Seems awfully.. inelegant (which is if anything a complaint about ts, not your solution per se), but if it works it works.

Do you think I'd be off base to think ts "should" be able to infer those added optional keys, or is there something deeper that I'm not understanding?

I explained in the first comment: extra properties are not prohibited in TS. See this playground link. Unmentioned properties can be anything at all.  They've declined this before, see ms/TS#56264 and ms/TS#33736

You can get proper type lowering if you replace the m.destinationUserID !== undefined with "destinationUserID" in m

Yeah, TS excess property checking behavior is kind of a mess/minefield. Some features pretend excess properties are prohibited (object literals, and the in operator check), whereas others are sticklers about excess properties being allowed and unknown (optional chaining operator).  You can either build your own safe union {a: string, b?: string} | {a?: string, b: string}, or use {a: string} | {b: string} with the in operator.

@jcalz I understand that ts will allow extra properties. What I was getting hung up on is why let emailAddress = ('destinationAddress' in m) ? m.destinationAddress : undefined and let emailAddress = m?.destinationAddress seem like they should be functionally equivalent but ts rejects the latter. Your comment that "excess property checking behavior is kind of a mess/minefield" may be the closest I can get to a satisfactory answer on that one though.
